# java wont run under chroot cause it can not find shared libraries

Tags: linux, java, ruby

i have openjdk and jRuby installed and running properly.

however when i run exactly same environment under chroot, i get:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

i can see the libs, they are in place.

played with setting `PATH`, `JAVA_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to correct values.

did not help.

any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

seems you did not mount `proc` under your chroot.

try to mount its own `proc` by:

```
# inside chroot
mount -t proc none /proc
```

or to "share" system's proc by:

```
# outside chroot
mount -o bind /proc /path/to/chroot/proc
```